# How does website project define the reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

All, Web Site project in visual studio doesn't have project file like web application project.
In the project file we always can find the reference definition in there .

But in the web site project ,Where is it defined ?How and where can it find the reference dll when it start up in the host web server like IIS. Thanks.

Comment: not really an answer but : transform website to web application

Comment: @lordkain :) Is there any good reason to do that ? thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

It was defined in the solution file which include the web site . If you use the text editor to open the `*.sln` file. you can find the `ProjectReferences` element in the xml. Hope it is helpful. thanks.

Comment: I mean how the web site can find and load reference dll when start up or compile